# How to perform sort and limit on whole group by in MongoDB - mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to apply sort on the whole group and limit the results.
But my below mongoose code sorts the group on the mentioned limit.

```
collection.aggregate([
{ $sort : {NAME: -1}} ,
{ $match : { NAME : {$regex : `.*${query.NAME.toUpperCase()}.*`} } },
{ $group : { _id : "$NAME", NAME:{$first:"$NAME"} }},
{ $skip : 1},
{ $limit : 10}],function(err,data){}
```

Let's say it sort first 10 results in the group, instead of sorting everything and show the first 10 results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't you think it'll create the problem because in first 10 might get name starts with Z alphabet, in another 10 you get name starts with A?

Comment: Yes, that's why I want to sort all data and do aggregation on top of it

Answer (score 0):

See this link [to the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-limit-memory-optimization). I haven't tested this since I haven't got the environment, nor the database to do so, but, I believe you might want to put your `$sort` argument just before `$limit` in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. 
If you see my aggregate query the sort param is at 1st in array and limit is at last.

Comment: I insist on the "**just**" in "just before". I don't know if it would change something in your query, but It might. :)